# Xamarin.Forms.Maps map appears dark only on one android device

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.forms

I'm using the Xamarin.Forms.Maps package to create a basic street map within a Stack Layout.

The map arrears as it should on both Android and iOS apart from on a smaller Android phone (Samsung Galaxy Ace to be exact).

On this device the map appears to have a strange dark overlay on it.

I'm not setting this anywhere, and like I say it's fine everywhere else.

Has anyone come across this, and if so how did you get round it, as I'm not sure how to even debug this.

thanks

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             x:Class="ax_mobile_app.Views.Map.MapPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
             Title="Map" >

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem x:Name="backItem" 
                     Text="Back" 
                     Clicked="GoBack" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Gray">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" Padding="10,10,10,10">
                <maps:Map
                x:Name="MyMap"
                IsShowingUser="True"
                MapType="Street"
            />
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested, I changed my minimum Android version from API level 10 to level 18 and the weird darkness was gone...